# Multiple Threads within a loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpool

I am trying to make a matrix addition program through multithreading, in which i have to divide the rows of both matrices and run them in a separate thread, after that combine all the threads to get the final addition matrix.

i have made the program through single thread but unable to get that done with multiple threads.

this code is for addition with single thread

```
   class Program
    {
        static void matrixAdd()
        {
            int[,] a = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
            int[,] b = { { 4, 8, 7 }, { 6, 5, 4 }, { 3, 2, 1 } };
            int[,] c = new int[3, 3];


            int f = c.Length;
            int i, m = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int n = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" ");

                for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" " + a[i, j]);
                }

            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (m = 0; m < 3; m++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" ");

                for (n = 0; n < 3; n++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" " + b[m, n]);
                }

            }
            Console.Write("\n");


            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
                {

                    Console.Write(a[k, l] + b[k, l] + "\t");
                }
            }


        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Thread t1 = new Thread(matrixAdd);

            t1.Start();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: And what is your question? Give us exacly what is your problem and we will be glad to help, but we wont finish the task for you. Post attempts, and we will point you into right direction, post errors and we will try to fix them With You, not for you. Hope you understand.

Comment: Before we can help you, we need you to [edit] your question and provide: (1) an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), (2) a detailed description of the error or problematic output you're getting, and (3) your goal. See [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).